# tag laplace-expansion

Tags: support, tagging

The tag [laplace-expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laplace-expansion) seem to be used for two totally different, and unrelated subjects:

1) Laplace approximation for integrals, as in [Laplace's method with nontrivial parameter dependency](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052676/laplaces-method-with-nontrivial-parameter-dependency)

2) Laplace expansion for calculating determinants, as used in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122984/proof-for-determinants-using-laplace-and-induction

I guess the second use is the intended use, but as there (was) no [tag wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/laplace-expansion/info) it's difficult to say!

Proposal: Define 2) as the intended use, and make a new tag laplace-approximation for 1)

Comment: Good catch on this tag! I think a separate tag should be created maybe called "laplace-method" or something along those lines for the integration technique with [tag:laplace-expansion] being reserved for the matrix technique.

Answer (score 3):

As of @Cameron Williams comment, I will go on implementing the change with new tag laplace-method, and propose tag wikis for both tags, in short time, unless protested at here.

Comment: Good idea! I'm all for it. I don't see why anyone would object (and surely they had their chance to do so anyway).

Comment: Done now, hopefully correctly.